# Superconductivity in space

Tags: superconductivity

Do you think you could use the drastically reduced temperatures in space to create superconductivity on the outside of a ship, for power on the inside, preventing overheating, and a near constant acceleration? Do space stations ever use reduced temperatures for special purposes?

Comment: Space has a temperature of approx. 2.7K, so if you shield parts of a spacecraft against sunlight, it will cool down to that temperature, eventually, which is a very convenient one for superconductors. There are some technical problems with that, though. For one thing the radiation flux at 10K is only 0.57mW/m^2, so cooling becomes extremely inefficient. That's why spacecraft with cryogenic detectors are usually carrying a supply of liquid Helium. Radiation cooling just doesn't cut it, not even for detectors. Superconductors would still not give you "near constant acceleration", though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why superconductors aren't used in space?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/99471/why-superconductors-arent-used-in-space)

Comment: A lab on the dark side of the moon might work too. But I was thinking space station/factory/research lab.