# Would it be possible for superconductors to work using the coldness of space?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, temperature, superconductivity, space

Some temperatures and numbers to work with... The baseline temperature of outer space, as set by the background radiation from the Big Bang, is 2.7 K (−270.45 °C; −454.81 °F)

The temperatures for superconductivity to work in copper oxide-based ceramic materials — work only below 133 K (−140 °C).

Another thing to keep in mind with superconductors is both pressure and temperature play a role in the state of the material’s conductivity.

Could some sort of insulation from radiation and light in space keep the temperature low enough for superconductivity to work in space?

Comment: Hey, have you looked at this : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/99471/why-superconductors-arent-used-in-space?rq=1 ?

Comment: The actual question is whether the "high-temperature" superconductors, being brittle ceramics and supporting relatively low current density, are a right choice for your planned mission. If so, keep them shielded from the sun and they will stay superconductive almost forever, as you expect.

Comment: Just checked it out, it sounds like some sort of coolant is required to keep superconductors cold enough to work in our solar system because of solar radiation from the sun.

Comment: You would need coolant for the higher-performance type-I superconductors. For HT SC, an aluminum foil (or gold-plated mylar) shielding the sun radiation should suffice.